# getting a windows form app written in C# Textbox to output text that you want

Tags: c#, winforms

In my app, the user will select a material type like steel/stainless steel from a ComboBox, select the kind of drill (eg. faststeel) in another ComboBox and
the drill diameter in a NumericUpDown. The RPM TextBox should then display the automatically calculated RPM.

Right now, the RPM TextBox stays empty until I click on it and change the value.

```
namespace BoorCalc
{
    public partial class boorCalcForm : Form
    {
        public string materiaal;
        public string soortboor;
        public decimal diameter;
        decimal VC;
        string RPM;


        public boorCalcForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }             

        public void boorCalcForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {       

        }  

        public void materiaalDropBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            materiaal = materiaalDropBox.Text;                 
        }

        public void soortBoorDropBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            soortboor = soortBoorDropBox.Text;                
        }

        public void diameterValue_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            diameter = diameterValue.Value;                       
        }

        public void toerentalValue_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (materiaal == "RVS")
            {
                VC = 318 * 30;
                RPM = Convert.ToString(VC / diameter);
            }
                toerentalValue.Text =  RPM;
        }
     }

}
```

How do I change my code so that the RPM TextBox immediately show the calculated RPM without clicking on it.

Comment: Is there any chance you could upload your code to Github (or any other public code repository) so we can download and have a look? Might also be useful if you could post a screenshot of the user interface to make sense so that we can make sense of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: We don't put "answered" in the title here.  You've accepted an answer, that's good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your toerentalValue.Text is only updated on toerentalValue_TextChanged. If you want it to be updated when you change the diameter, run/call the calculation on diameterValue_ValueChanged. A very dirty solution is

```
public void diameterValue_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    diameter = diameterValue.Value;
    toerentalValue_TextChanged(sender, e);           
}
```

A better solution is to generalize and split the calculation elsewhere so you don't mix UI and logic.

Comment: thank you!
if i understand correctly i made the mistake of expecting the textbox to show the result of a calculation that didn't happen yet?

i did an even dirtier thing now just for now to make it work real quick, tomorrow ill try to make it better,  i copied everything i had in tourentalvalue_textchanged  and put it in the diameter one, it works now, thanks!

Comment: Sorta. I think you mixed what it means by TextChanged event, if it's indeed not editable by the user, then it doesn't even have to listen to TextChanged event, it's the *other* controls (the comboboxes and the numericupdown) that should trigger the (re)calculation.

Comment: ahh,  thanks that makes sense, you've been a great help.